# development environment setup - iphone iOS using C# web services and MS SQLServer

Tags: c#, ios, sql-server-2008, development-environment

What would be the best (or easiest) way to setup a development environment in order to:
- develop iOS(iphone) application using Xcode in a MAC 
- iphone app will be calling .NET web services written in C# (windows laptop) 
- the database is MS SQLServer 2008 R2 (windows laptop)

I understand that I could do all this in my MAC if I was using PHP/MySQL but I really need the C#/MS SQL combo.

Thanks in advance.

Ceta

Comment: here is the question you need to ask.. MAC OS can it run .NET FrameWork.. I am not sure because I am not a MAC Guy.. I prefer Windows OS.. so If I were to even take a guess.. I am gonna Say. NO..! different Operating Systems.. and IPhones us Objective C or you could do it using Mono as well

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is asking for discussion, and isn't really programming (code) related. It's not a good fit for the question and answer design of SO. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) can provide some help in deciding what kinds of things should be asked here. Following the site guidelines helps keep SO a useful reference site. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to a dedicated Windows environment for development, I would suggest that you install [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html) or [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) on your Mac, and do your Windows development in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just deploy the Webservices (on the web?) and just test your API calls remotely?

Alternatively, network the machines so you can access the development copy, or use something like Parallels Desktop to run Windows inside your Mac environment. Related: [Visual Studio on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413820/visual-studio-on-a-mac)

Answer (score 0):

If you have both machines up and running, XCODE, VS and SQL Server already installed, then I don't see the problem.

You only need to configure the special things in your Windows Machine so its perfectly suited for Web Services development. Skip the steps you may already have done.

1) Install IIS 6 / 7 (depends on your windows version)
2) Install ASP.NET
3) Turn off your firewall for Home network, or configure some permission for allowing inbound traffic to the HTTP/HTTPS ports.
4) Make sure you have an static IP address in your home network, or, make sure your machine name is DNS resolvable from your Mac.

You need IIS because Visual Studio internal web server doesn't allow remote connections.

Now, how can you debug your C# code if the Web Service is running in IIS? two options:

1) (easy) In the solution explorer, right click on your web project, choose properties, chose Web, in the section named "Servers" choose use local IIS WebServer and name your virtual folder. You'll be able to debug easily.

2) (medium) You can just publish your web app to your local IIS, make it run, and then from visual studio using the debug -> attach to process menu attach yourself to the w3wp.exe. The problem is, if you have several application pools, have fun finding your application.